# Redirect and set value process

Tags: oracle-apex

hope somebody here can help me.

I have 2 selects list, among many text fields that need to be filled by the users. The first select list checks the State people are, and the second uses that first select list value, to show only towns that are located in that state.

Problem is, everytime the user selects the state, as I'm using a "redirect and set value" property to be used by the following select list, I lost all values in my text fields on the page refresh that takes place because of the redirect.

How do I keep the values in the text fields intact while being able to reload the page so the value of the select list can be checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dkage If you use APEX 4 or above, there is Cascading Select List http://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/oracle-apex-4-0-cascading-lovsselect-lists/

For example:

1. Create parent select list (P3_SL1) with "Page action when value changed" property set to "None (default)"

   ```
   SELECT state_name d, st r
     FROM demo_states
   ```
2. Create child select list (P3_SL2) with "Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)" set to parent select list name "P3_SL1" and query like

   ```
   SELECT cust_last_name d, customer_id r
     FROM demo_customers
    WHERE cust_state = :P3_SL1
   ```